# Windows Command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Need to find the last underscore in a filename and remove everything following it(including the last underscore).

eg Filename:

```
abc_erf_dsgd_fd12458.txt
```

expected result:

```
abc_erf_dsgd.txt
```

Note:The no:of underscores appearing the filename is dynamic and is not fixed in nature.

Certain files may have only 2 underscores whereas others may have upto 6.
Intention here is to find out the last underscore and omit everything following it.

Preferably windows batch script which could do the trick and not powershell commands.

Comment: So write a loop that checks from the end of the filename for the first occurrence of a underscore?

Comment: What do you mean with remove? Rename the file, put the new name in a var?

Comment: Pretty simple with the [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081) - `jren "_[^_]*(?=\.[^.]*$)" ""`. The utility is pure script (hybrid batch / JScript) that runs on any Windows version from XP onward.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo off
set file=abc_erf_dsgd_fd12458.txt
for %%A in (%file%) do set Ext=%%~xA
set remove=%file%
:loop
if "%remove%" neq "%remove:*_=%" Set "remove=%remove:*_=%"&goto :loop
call set filenew=%%file:_%remove%=%%%Ext%"
set file
```

Sample output:

```
> SU_1220967.cmd
file=abc_erf_dsgd_fd12458.txt
filenew=abc_erf_dsgd.txt"
```

The batch

- first gets the extension into var `Ext`
- then creates a var `remove` containing the remainder of the file name after removing all text up to and including the underscore in a loop by using string substitution.
- builds the new file name by substituting the `remove` with nothing and reapplying the extension

Comment: Thanks for this solution.I was looking for  a batch script which could actually rename a file available in a particular windows folder.Giving below the code snippet that i am currently using for renaming the files,considering that the files have only one underscore appearing in the file name.I want to modify this code such that it identifies the last '_'  in the filename,and rename it@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
cd C:\Users\ambika.narayan.rao\JenkinsWorkspace
SET "fname=*.pjb"
FOR %%i IN ("%fname%") DO FOR /f "delims=_" %%j IN ("%%i") DO ren "%%~i" "%%~j%%~xi"
GOTO :EOF

Comment: Provided there is only one underscore, change the for command `FOR %%i IN ("%fname%") DO FOR /f "delims=_" %%j IN ("%%~ni") DO ren "%%~i" "%%~dpi%%~j%%~xi"` As the dfault is `tokens=1` this should do.